# Python(Pandas) fills blanks cells

Tags: python, pandas, cells

I am using Python(Pandas) to manipulate high frequency data. Basically, I need to fill the blank cells.

If the this row is blank, then this row will be filled in with the previous existed observation.

My original data example:

```
Time    bid    ask    
15:00    .      .
15:00    .      .
15:02    76     .
15:02    .      77
15:03    .      .
15:03    78     .
15:04    .      .
15:05    .      80
15:05    .      .
15:05    .      .
```

needs to converted to

```
Time    bid    ask    
15:00    .      .
15:00    .      .
15:02    76     .
15:00    76     77
15:00    76     77
15:00    78     77
15:00    78     77
15:00    78     80
15:05    78     80
15:05    78     80
```

**This is my code:**

```
#Import
tan=pd.read_csv('sample.csv')

#From here fill the blank cells

first_line = True
mydata = []
with open(tan, 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
# loop through each row...
for row in reader:
    this_row = row
    # now do the blank-cell checking...
    if first_line:
        for colnos in range(len(this_row)):
            if this_row[colnos] == '':
                this_row[colnos] = 0
        first_line = False
    else:
        for colnos in range(len(this_row)):
            if this_row[colnos] == '':
                this_row[colnos] = prev_row[colnos]
    mydata.append( [this_row] )
    prev_row = this_row
```

However, the code does not work.

System indicates:

```
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, DataFrame found
```

I really appreciated if your can help me to solve this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Use `fillna()` property. You can specify the method as `forward fill` as follows

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('sample.csv')
data = data.fillna(method='ffill') # This one forward fills all the columns.
# You can also apply to specific columns as below
# data[['bid','ask']] = data[['bid','ask']].fillna(method='ffill')
print data
    Time  bid      ask    
0  15:00  NaN      NaN
1  15:00  NaN      NaN
2  15:02   76      NaN
3  15:02   76       77
4  15:03   76       77
5  15:03   78       77
6  15:04   78       77
7  15:05   78       80
8  15:05   78       80
9  15:05   78       80
```

Comment: R u sure this code is exactly the one I was asking ? This one looks so simple ~

Comment: Try it out..!!! Pandas functions for data manipulation and cleansing are powerful and easy..

Answer (score 5):

There is the lesser known `ffill` method:

```
In [102]:
df.ffill()

Out[102]:
    Time  bid  ask
0  15:00  NaN  NaN
1  15:00  NaN  NaN
2  15:02   76  NaN
3  15:02   76   77
4  15:03   76   77
5  15:03   78   77
6  15:04   78   77
7  15:05   78   80
8  15:05   78   80
9  15:05   78   80
```